# How to make navbar overflow hidden on Firefox/IE

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, overflow

I have a problem to achieve overflow hidden on bootstrap navbar.
I want navbar elements to be hidden if page width is smaller.
I have it working on chrome using:

`white-space: nowrap; overflow: hidden;`

But it doesn't work on firefox  and IE. Elements are wrapped in two or more lines.

This is example: [plunker example](http://plnkr.co/edit/Z0p1FsgLGc0nf111hEt0)

I have tried also:
`overflow-x: hidden;`
but it doesn't work on FIrefox/IE either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `float: left` use

```
display: inline-block;
```

on `li` elements.

(Tested on firefox)